# PHP broken code on local machine but working on staging server

Tags: php, debugging, syntax-error

I'm having a strange issue here, i have this bit of code:

```
<?php
if ($node->nid == "1") {
    include 'front.tpl.php';
    return;
} else { 
?>

    <div id="left-col" class="grid_9">
        <h1><?php print $title ?></h1>
        <hr />
        <?php global $user;if ( $is_admin ) { ?>[<a href="/node/<?php print $node->nid ?>/edit">Edit</a>]<? } ?>
            <?php if ($show_messages) { print $messages; } ?>
                <?php print $help ?>
            <?php print $content; ?>        
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This exact code is working fine on the staging server, i've litrally just installed a LAMP stack using XAMPP and downloaded the code from the server.

PHP is now throwing this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in F:\Workspace\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\node.tpl.php on line 19
```

Anyone have any ideas what it could be? i have a feeling it "might" be due to the jumping in and out of  tags but i'm not certain, can anyone shed some light on this. (this might be a server issue in which case i will also happily take advice on what php.ini settings need to be poked in the right direction!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both machines running the same version of PHP with the same settings in PHP.ini?

Comment: Are you using some kind of templating engine ? (your file's name "node.tpl.php" might suggest this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is the server doesn't have short tag support turned on.

```
<? } ?>
```

Comment: perfect, that was it, didn't see that cheeky short tag there on the side. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 good eyesight! Might help to keep the `<?php ... { ?>`...`<?php } ?>` structures on a consistently-indented line of their own, to make this easier to spot?

Comment: any idea how to make server to support short tag? is it possible somehow?